# If child element has class then alert

Tags: jquery, chat, appendchild

I am trying to make a simple chat action where me is the first user and you is the second user. All I am trying to put input text into `ul li`. condition if last `ul` has class me then alert me else alert you. Kindly advice.

Following is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat-left">
    <div class="msg-area">
        <ul class="me">
            <li>what is this msg</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="you">
            <li>others message</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <form id="me">
        <input type="text" name="mymsg" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#me').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('left');
        var $mymsg = $('input[type="text"]').val();
        $(this).siblings('.msg-area ul').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('me')) {
                console.log('me');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `siblings('.msg-area ul')` won't work because `ul` is not a sibling element, you need to use `siblings('.msg-area').find('ul')`

You don't need to have a loop to do that

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#me').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var mymsg = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();

    var $last = $(this).siblings('.msg-area').find('ul:last');
    if ($last.hasClass('me')) {
      $('#log').html('me')
    } else {
      $('#log').html('you')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<div class="chat-left">
  <div class="msg-area">
    <ul class="me">
      <li>what is this msg</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="me">
      <li>others message</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <form id="me">
    <input type="text" name="mymsg" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Arun your code worked like a charm. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$(this).siblings('.msg-area').find('ul.me').each(function() {
    console.log('me');
});
```